# How to use multiselect in codeception and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, codeception

Is it possible to use multiselect boxes on Codeception?

My form code:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-vertical" id="solicitor-form" method="POST" action="http://mytest.dev/role">
  <select multiple="true" id="optgroup" name="solicitor[]">
     <option value="1" selected>Yorkshire</option>
     <option value="2" selected>Quarry</option>
     <option value="3" selected>William Hurst</option>
  </select></div></div>                            
  <input class="btn-large btn-success btn" type="submit" value="Update Access">
</form>
```

I've tried something like this for the test:

```
 $i->SeeOptionIsSelected("#solicitor-form", 'Yorkshire');
 $i->SeeOptionIsSelected("#solicitor-form", 'Quarry');
```

But codeception fails on SECOND select. So then I tried this:

```
 $i->SeeOptionIsSelected('#solicitor-form select[name=solicitor[]]', 'Yorkshire');
 $i->SeeOptionIsSelected('#solicitor-form select[name=solicitor[]]', 'Quarry');
```

but it doesnt seem to resolve `solicitor[]` correctly, specifically the `[]` because it trips itself up with the pattern match.

Edit: I tried Daverts answer like this:

```
$i->selectOption('optgroup',array('Quarry', 'Yorkshire'));
```

But this is the output when running the test:

```
* I select option "optgroup","lambda function"
```

It seems the "lambda function" is not returning the correct result?

Comment: Lambda function is simply meaning an anonymous function, which array('Quarry', 'Yorkshire') is. Does the code function correctly? Also, I thought this was about he seeOptionIsSelected() function rather than the selectOption()?

Comment: Basically the code that Davert posted below does not work - it does not select anything and my test fails...

Comment: The test actually fails from it? In your HTML you seem to be defining them as already selected, in which case trying to select them again using `selectOption()` will result in it just skipping over them.

Comment: I've tried with/without selected etc. The test 'fails' after I click the submit button and check for a result - there was no selection included on the input, so my seeInDatabase() fails. So the test is 'failing' because the selects are not actually selected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for a delay.
It looks like this feature was not documented. Sorry, I totally forgot to update docs, when released 1.6.3.

You can pass an array of options as a second parameter to select multiple options.

```
    $I->amOnPage('/form/select_multiple');
    $I->selectOption('What do you like the most?',array('Play Video Games', 'Have Sex'));
    $I->click('Submit');
```

Thanks, I will update a reference soon.

Comment: thanks Davert - that seems close - but there is a bug/error. I've editted my question. I am running Codecept.phar version 1.6.3.1

Answer (score 2):

The bug is exactly with [] as far as I can see in my application, for example I have this select:

```
<select multiple="true" class="span h300" id="products[]" name="products[]">...</select>
```

and when I do:

```
$I->selectOption('Products', array('value', 'someOtherValue') );
```

I'll get the same error as you do.

As you can see I have some additional classes, .span and .h300 so I've used .h300 selector which is unique on that page and the test works perfectly, the values are in db and verification works as expected...

So to sum it up my selector which works is:

```
$I->selectOption('.h300', array('value', 'someOtherValue') );
```

Just my 2 cents on the issue, don't have enough time now to investigate what causes the problem with []...